# Elasticseach: Match phrase and term

Tags: elasticsearch

In elasticsearch, I'm constructing a filtered query in order to find documents that contain **both** a *phrase* and a *term*. The following query doesn't work. It seems to return the results with the items in the query array, but as if there was an 'or' operator applied.

EDIT: Since I'm using PHP, the following example is a php array.

```
'query' => [
    'filtered' => [
        'query' => [
            'match' => [
                "post_content" => [
                    'query' => ['ambulance services', 'veteran'],
                    'operator' => 'and',
                    'type' => 'phrase'
                ]
            ]
        ],
        'filter' => [
            ...
        ]
    ]
]
```

Comment: Could you post your mapping, and a few sample docs (the ones you expect to be returned)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never seen that syntax for the match query before where you can provide an array for the query like you have done.  But I did try that out in version 0.90 and saw that it just returned results for the second string.  So using JSON, what I tried was something like this:

```
{
    "query" : {
        "filtered" : {
            "query" : {
                "match" : {
                    "post_content" : {
                        "query" : [ "test string 1", "test string 2" ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you refer to the [match query docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html), the `and` operator ensures that all the terms are in the post_content field not taking positions of the terms into consideration.  I think the match query just boils down to a bool query where each term in the query is represented by a clause.  So the operator does not quite do what you want it to do.

I think the following will work for what you want:

```
{
    "query" : {
        "bool" : {
            "should" : [
                {
                    "match" : {
                        "post_content" : {
                            "type" : "phrase",
                            "query" : "ambulance services"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match" : {
                        "post_content" : {
                            "query" : "veteran"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "minimum_should_match" : 2
        }
    }
}
```